# How do I reuse ReactRootView in Android RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android, react-native, android-recyclerview

I need to embed a React Native view in my RecyclerView. I have created a simple wrapper layout which contains my `ReactRootView` which I inflate in the RecyclerView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <com.facebook.react.ReactRootView
        android:id="@+id/rootView"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Here is how I inflate the View:

```
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.react_native_wrapper, null);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}
```

And render the ReactRootView

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Bundle launchOptions = new Bundle();
    launchOptions.putInt("index", position);
    holder.reactRootView.startReactApplication(mReactInstanceManager, "HelloWorld", launchOptions);
}
```

When the ViewHolder is reused and `onBindViewHolder` is called again, I get an exception here: `holder.reactRootView.startReactApplication(mReactInstanceManager, "HelloWorld", launchOptions)`.

The error message: `java.lang.AssertionError: This root view has already been attached to a catalyst instance manager`

How do I reuse the ReactRootView instance? I do not face this error when I create a new ViewHolder for each item, but that defeats the purpose of a RecyclerView.

Comment: So have you considered detaching it first before attaching on binding?

Comment: I did. The view is detached in the `ReactInstanceManager`, but it does not update the `ReactRootView`. It still says, it is attached. I have used a hacky way to get around this problem:

Comment: oar.garuna Could you let me know what you used to get around this?

Comment: @Sammekl Add `startReactApplication` in `ViewHolder's` init